# Iterating over geoJSON

Tags: python, dictionary, geojson

My geoJSON looks like so

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
},

"features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "value1": "abc",
            "value2": 0,
            "value3": 0.99,
            "value4": "def",
            "value5": "882.3",
            "value6": 12,
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [1, 1]
        }
    }
]
}
```

I want to access `properties` and check some `values` for a `key`

```
for features in geoJsonPoints["features"]:
    for interesting in features["properties"]["value1"]:
        print interesting
        print "!"
```

I get

> a
>
> !
>
> b
>
> !
>
> c
>
> !

Why is that?! It seems like my loop does not return me a dictionary?!

If I do this

```
for features in geoJsonPoints["features"]:
    for interesting in features["properties"]:
        print type(intereseting)
        print interesting
```

I get

> type 'unicode'
>
> value1
>
> type 'unicode'
>
> value2
>
> ...

Why isnt that a dictionary? And, if its not a dictionary, why can I access the values behind the "unicode" like in the first loop I showed?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`features["properties"]["value1"]` points to `abc` string which you iterate over character by character. Instead, you probably meant to iterate over the `properties` dictionary:

```
for property_name, property_value in features["properties"].items():
    print(property_name, property_value)
```

Or, you can loop over the dictionary keys:

```
for property_name in features["properties"]:
    print(property_name, features["properties"][property_name])
```

See more about dictionaries and looping techniques here:

- [Dictonaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [Looping Techniques](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)
- [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python)

Comment: why do I need the `item()` for that?

Comment: @Stophface `items()` (as well as `iteritems()` in Python 2) gives you access to both keys and values at the same time. Please follow the posted links for more information. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, I thought when I can iterate like in my first loop through a dictionary, why can't i do it in my nested loop then?

Comment: @Stophface `features["properties"]` in your case is a dictionary. If you iterate over it as `for interesting in features["properties"]`, you will get the keys only (well, you would be able to access values as `features["properties"][interesting]` of course). But `items()` allows you to access both keys and values at the same time. Sorry, I'm quite terrible at explaining and teaching :)

Comment: "If you iterate over it as for interesting in features["properties"], you will get the keys only (well, you would be able to access values as features["properties"][interesting] of course)." Well thats problematic because it will, as my thread showed, return letter by letter?!

Comment: @Stophface nope, try it out, in this case `interesting` should contain your dictionary keys (`value1`, `value2` etc) and `features["properties"][interesting]` would contain dictionary values: (`abc`, `0` etc)..

Comment: nope. When I write `[interesting]` without quotationmarks it says `its not defined`. I thought so too (as i.e. here http://www.jroller.com/evans/entry/parsing_json_with_python). Have a look at my question. I basically wrote it the way you just suggested (except the quotationmarks). But I think the problem is that `properties` in my JSON is not written like so `[{...]}` but like so `{}`. Try it out, it wont work.

Comment: @Stophface okay, could you try the second code snippet I've posted? The one after `Or, you can loop over the dictionary keys`. Thanks.

Comment: That does not work. It says `property_name` (which i replaced with `value1`) not defined. `print property_name` works! I am on python 2.7 btw.